# How to facilitate the type refactoring of a C# variable?

Tags: c#, generics, types, refactoring

For example, I have a code fragment like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> _en;
object _lock = new Object();

void Enumerate()
{
    IEnumerable<int> en = null;

    lock (_lock)
    {
        en = _en;
        _en = new List<int>();
        // ...
    }

    foreach (var i in en)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to change the item type from `int` to `double`, so I have at least 3 places to attend and change it. To facilitate this, does something like the following make sense? Is there anything else I can do?

```
IEnumerable<int> _en;
object _lock = new Object();

void Enumerate()
{
    var en = GetDefault(_en);

    lock (_lock)
    {
        en = _en;
        _en = CreateEmptyList(_en);
        // ...
    }

    foreach (var i in en)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

static T GetDefault<T>(T arg)
{
    return default(T);
}

static List<T> CreateEmptyList<T>(IEnumerable<T> arg)
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```

Comment: Basing the architecture of your application on the potential for refactoring seems like the wrong reasoning.

Comment: If the class that owns `_en` were itself generic, it doesn't seem like you would have an issue.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin, could you explain how this is an architectural issue?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot, it is not generic. Basically, it is the code manipulating the ViewModel.

Comment: You're saying you might need to refactor the code at some point and change lists of int to lists of double, and are concerned for having to modify the code in multiple places. To write a whole bunch of code solely for that purpose seems like a waste. If you need generics (I.e., a list of int or a list of double might be passed in here, and you don't know at design time which it will be, then use generics). It seems like you want to anticipate future refactoring (not programmatic but actual code changes), which may never occur, and design an architecture based on that. This is over-engineering.

Comment: Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @DavidKhaykin, I am not responsible for the Model, the other developer is. But I am responsible for some business logic that operates on the model. At this stage, the basic types of the model may change frequently. I want to make my life easier by using refactoring, instead of manually doing every single change like in my example. It's up to you decide if your misunderstood the question.

Comment: Ok, then I'm deciding that I did not, in fact misunderstand the question :) So you're expecting many changes and want to save on menial work. Ok, I get that. You can make a generic base class and then build the other classes on top of it. I'll cook up an example.

Comment: Why are you passing an arg to `CreateEmptyList<T>()`? Is there more code in there?

Comment: @KeithPayne, no more code. The only goal is to infer the type of the argument and create an empty `List` of that type. So I don't have to use `List<int>` explicitly. Note, I use `int` only in single place in my second code listing.

Comment: @avo I realize it isn't generic, it *should* be. At least, the logic you're looking for should be defined in a base class which is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

As I have decided to understand it, you want to minimize effort of menial refactoring tasks amongst constantly changing requirements in your work environment by creating some way of lowering the number of overall places you'd need to change code during this refactoring.

**One Possible Solution:**

*You can obfuscate to a point.*

**Important Note:** Places where your code is called may have to be refactored if you want to change from, double to int. Basically covariance and contravariance comes into play.

```
double example = 2; // works
int example2 = 2.5; // needs to manually be refactored
```

- So with that in mind, you can create your class as a generic base class that accepts a `value type` and you'd then create a pass-through subclass that defines that `value type` (int, double, etc.).
- You'd want to provide methods that don't require the explicit creation of, say List all over the place because then when refactoring, all that has to be changed.

Here's an example of a method that can do something like this:

```
// We use params T[] here to reduce the need for any calling code to declare,
// for example, a List<int>, which would later need to potentially be changed in
// many places.
public void SetEnumerable(params T[] value)
{
    _en = value;
}
```

- And you would call it with just the numeric values: (As per my first note, if you change the underlying generic type from `int` to `double`, this will continue to work; however if you change from `double` to `int`, then the calling code won't compile until it is refactored.

Example:

```
// Here we use the SetEnumerable method without declaring a List<int>.
// Therefore, if you later change underlying type to double, the code 
// below can remain unchanged.
var myEnumerable = new MyEnumerable();
myEnumerable.SetEnumerable(1, 2, 3);
```

**The class structure could look something like this:**

Note I'm not suggesting this is a great practice, and am merely attempting to provide a possible solution to your distinct problem in this case. *The merits of this solution in terms of performance and/or whether it's a good idea are outside the scope of this answer* :)

```
public class MyEnumerable : EnumerateBase<int> { }

public class EnumerateBase<T> where T :  struct 
{
    private IEnumerable<T> _en;
    object _lock = new Object();

    public void SetEnumerable(params T[] value)
    {
        _en = value;
    }

    public void Enumerate()
    {
        IEnumerable<T> en = null;

        lock (_lock)
        {
            en = _en;
            _en = new List<T>();
            // ...
        }

        foreach (var i in en) { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

In this example, the datatype `int` is only declared in one place, making refactoring relatively simple.

Hopefully, this gives you some food for thought and insight into how to approach your stated  problem.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. I think this would be overkill, especially if I have more than one field to refactor. I will however accept this as an answer if other people vote for it.

Comment: @avo - if it helps you then accept otherwise don't. However, this being overkill is exactly what I was trying to tell you in my comments :)